# fscanf - How to know if EOF means end of file or reading/another error?

Tags: c, file, io, scanf, eof

I have a question about I/O in C language, how can I make a difference to know if the lecture of my file has ended or if the data can't be read (or has a problem) as in the both cases, fscanf returns EOF ?

Comment: Use `feof` and `ferror`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don´t rely *only* on the return value of `fscanf()`, rely beside this one on [`feof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) and [`ferror()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) **after** the call to `fscanf()`:

```
FILE* file;
if((file == fopen("file.txt","r")) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "File could not be opened!");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

char buf;

/******************************************************************************/

while(fscanf(file,"%c",buf) == 1) {     // checks if an error was happen, else 
                                        // iterate to catching characters.
   /* handling of read character */
}

if(ferror(file))                        // checks if an I/O error occurred.
{
   // I/O error handling
   fprintf(stderr,"Input/Output error at reading file!");
   clearerr(file);
   // Further actions
}
else if(feof(file))                     // checks if the end of the file is reached.       
{
   // end of file handling
   fprintf(stderr,"Reached End of File!");
   clearerr(file);
   // Further actions
}

/******************************************************************************/

if(fclose(file) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "File could not be closed properly!");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! I still have an issue, when I se for ex :
`if (fscanf("%d %d %d..", &a , &b ...) != X )`
Then I start handling my errors using feof and ferror, it seems to work good but when there is no error but by input file does not contains X elements I also wanted to throw an error,
Then I tried with a file containing X-1 elements, and nothing happened.. 
So my two questions here, if we scanf more elements than available elements in the file does ferror launch an error ? If not why my solution did not work.. :/

Comment: Hello ! It's now fixed! I have to stock what fscanf returns in a variable to check if it's less than X in my example, before checking the end of file !

Comment: @MehdiZayene You can also use another condition after `else if(feof(file){}` for that case to explicitly handle failures which occurred **after** the first receiving argument was assigned successfully, like: `else if(feof(file){} else{ /* handle error if not all conversions could have been executed successfully */}` since all other conditions did not match and this is the only issue that could remain.

Comment: @MehdiZayene I think if the end of the file have not been reached **before** the first assignment and the assignment is successful, `fscanf()` won´t return `EOF` even if it has reached the end of file. Consider that quote: "*Return values - Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.*" - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Yes sure! Done :)

Answer (score 1):

As per [`fscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) return value:

[ISO/IEC 9899:2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)

> **§ 7.21.6.2 - 16** - The `fscanf` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

`EOF` is a macro with the value of `-1`, by itself it's not distinguishable as for the reasons why it occurs.

For this distinction **§ 7.21.6.2 - 19** recommends the use of [`feof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) for end-of-file and [`ferror()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) for I/O error:

> **EXAMPLE 3** To accept repeatedly from `stdin` a quantity, a unit of measure, and an item name:
>
> ```
> #include<stdio.h> 
>
> /*...*/
>
> int count; floatquant; 
> charunits[21],  item[21]; 
>
> do { 
>     count = fscanf(stdin, "%f%20sof%20s", &quant, units, item);
>     fscanf(stdin,"%*[^\n]"); 
> } while(!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin));
> ```

My usual approach when reading formated input, is to check the inputed values. For a sample input of 2 integers you can do something like:

```
int a, b;
FILE* file;
//open file to read
while(fscanf(file, "%d %d", &a, &b) == 2){ //read each 2 integers in the file, stop when condition fails, i.e. there are nothing else to read or the read input is not an integer
    //...handle inputs
}
```

This kind of read is safe and addresses all failure scenarios since it works for bad input and for "end of file".

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is how to distinguish end-of-file from an I/O error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this DV is totally uncalled for, my answer fully addresses the question with bonus info.

Comment: The OP wants to distinguish between end of file and I/O error. In both cases, `fscanf` returns `EOF`. The question is asking for a way to tell the difference between an `EOF` returned because the end of file was reached and an `EOF` returned because an I/O error occurred (such as a network connection failing, the file being already closed, some device error occurring, and so on). This answer contains nothing to provide that information.

Comment: One more example of the invisible blockquote. Quotes from the C Standard used to stand out clearly and elegantly.  Support reversing this decision... see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394644/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-contrast-for-blockquotes-such-as-the-old-style-w

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I considered your critic and recognize it's merit, I edited my answer.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes, yes, it was mutch better.